# Error in query, response is that row exists but value is None

Tags: python, database, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I creating my first bot using `Flask`, `Twilio`, `Dialogflow` to be deployed at `Heroku`. My local development is using `SQLite` but final version should use `POSTGRES`.

Yesterday as I began to store data to local db, I started getting this error as I try to identify the user that is sending message.

The idea is that, after user is created at db, I will store every message that he sent and every response given by `dialogflow`. But even though the user is being created at my db, I'm failing to query for his `user_id` afterwards.

Since it's not an actual error, but not finding the user, I'm posting the code below and printing some parts of it that I'm being trying to use to debug.

CODE:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from twilio.twiml.messaging_response import MessagingResponse

from sportsbot.utils import fetch_reply

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///myDB.db' #path to database and its name
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False #supress warning of changes on database
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
#app.debug = True

from sportsbot.models import User, Team, Matches, Messages

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return "hello world!"

@app.route('/whatsapp', methods=['POST'])
def sms_reply():
    "Check if user is new, create user at db if it is"
    phone_no = int(request.form.get('From').split(':')[1][1:])
    if User.query.filter(User.user_phone_no == phone_no).count() == 0:
        user = User(user_phone_no=phone_no)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        print("New user")
    else:
        print("User already at base")

    #tring to debug
    print(phone_no)
    user_id = User.query.filter(User.user_phone_no == phone_no).first()
    print(user_id)

    msg = request.form.get('Body')
    reply = fetch_reply(msg,phone_no)
    
    
    "Reply to it"
    print(reply['text'])
    print(reply['intent'])
    resp = MessagingResponse()
    resp.message(reply['text'])

    #message = Messages(user_id = user_id, message= msg, response=reply['text'],intent=reply['intent'])
    #db.session.add(message)
    #try:
     #   db.session.commit()
    #except:
     #   db.session.rollback()

    return str(resp)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

User class:

```
class User(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = db.Column(db.String(80), index = True, unique = False)
    user_phone_no = db.Column(db.Integer, index = True, unique = True)
    team_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('team.team_id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{}".format(self.user_name)
```

Prints:

```
User already at base
5511990046548
None
Oi! Bem Vindo ao EsporteBot. Você gostaria de saber sobre algum time ou quer a agenda de eventos da semana?
Default Welcome Intent
```

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong since it sees the user at db but cannot find it afterwards?

This code

```
User.query.filter(User.user_phone_no == phone_no).count()
```

finds 1 user

This code

```
user_id = User.query.filter(User.user_phone_no == phone_no).first()
```

gives `None` as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Code works correctly.

Problem is that in model `User` you created own `__repr__()` which displays `user_name` but you don't add `user_name` to database so it uses `None` as `user_name` and when you run `first()` then this `__repr__()` prints `None` as `user_name` - and this is why you get `None` on screen.

When you use

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "name: {}".format(self.user_name)
```

then you get `name: None` instead of `None`

Maybe better use

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "id: {}, name: {}, phone no: {}".format(self.user_id, self.user_name, self.user_phone_no)
```

to get more information.

Or simply remove `__repr__` from your model and then you will see something like `<User 1>`

---

Minimal working example which everyone can execute:

```
import os
from flask import Flask, request, render_template_string
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///myDB.db' #path to database and its name
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False #supress warning of changes on database
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
db.create_all()

class User(db.Model):
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_name = db.Column(db.String(80), index = True, unique = False)
    user_phone_no = db.Column(db.Integer, index = True, unique = True)
    
    def __repr__(self):
        #return "{}".format(self.user_name)
        #return "name: {}".format(self.user_name)
        return "id: {}, name: {}, phone no: {}".format(self.user_id, self.user_name, self.user_phone_no)

#db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return render_template_string("""
<form method="POST" action="/whatsapp">
Phone <input name="From" value="James Bond:+007"></input>
<button type="submit">OK</button>
</form>
""")

@app.route('/whatsapp', methods=['POST'])
def sms_reply():
    "Check if user is new, create user at db if it is"

    parts = request.form.get('From').split(':')

    user_name = parts[0]
    phone_no = int(parts[1][1:])

    if User.query.filter(User.user_phone_no == phone_no).count() == 0:
        #user = User(user_phone_no=phone_no)
        user = User(user_phone_no=phone_no, user_name=user_name)
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        print("New user")
    else:
        print("User already at base")

    #tring to debug
    print('phone_no:', phone_no)
    user = User.query.filter(User.user_phone_no == phone_no).first()
    print('user:', user)

    return render_template_string("""{{user}}""", user=user)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thnaks so much for your answer, it does get the job done.
Unfortunately, Twilio does not give me the username on WhatsApp, so I will need to prompt user in another question to have it